# How to deploy a smart contract using the second address in your Metamask wallet? using (Ethers.js and Hardhat)

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

Here is my deploy script.. it currently deploys my smart contract using the FIRST address in my metamask wallet. How to deploy with my SECOND?

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
  const CryptoBeetles = await ethers.getContractFactory("CryptoBeetles")
  const cryptoBeetles = await CryptoBeetles.deploy("CryptoBeetles", "CBEET")

  await cryptoBeetles.deployed()
  console.log(`Contract successfully deployed to ${cryptoBeetles.address}`)

  const newItemId = await cryptoBeetles.mint("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmSSup7fucACuiXLGJgTBQoKQ9uSiTx7zAGer6AFvVvNBY")
  console.log(`NFT minted successfully :: ${newItemId}`)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Are u using mnemonic in hardhat config ?

Comment: In a dotenv i am

Answer (score 1):

You can set several addresses in your javascript file using ethers and hardhat then you just need to specify which address you want to use to make a call.

Here is a link: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts#using-a-different-account

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Yes this method works

Comment: Happy to hear! Please mark my answer as accepted and give it a upvote so my post can help others. Thanks